# Communication Between Host Machine and VM on Win10 Times Out

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, port, ip-address

I'm running a Win10 virtual machine on VirtualBox from my Win10 host machine. (It's a long story but I needed to create one for development) Currently I am trying to connect to the VM from my host machine and I have both firewalls turned off for both machines but the connection from my host to VM keeps timing out.

I can ping the VM from my host and vice versa, so I know they can communicate right? *(I'm somewhat new to networks)* I also tried logging the dropped packets but nothing is getting written to the logs by win10 which leads me to believe it's being blocked..?

**Anyone have any ideas about how I can determine why my connection is still timing out?**

I used the sommand: **netstat -a -n** and for the state of my computer's IP address trying to connect to the VM's IP address is SYN_SENT

Comment: Which network type do you have set in VirtualBox? Also, what do you mean by "trying to connect" - i.e. what are you using to connect? Windows File Sharing? Remote Desktop? A web server? Something else?

Comment: I'm using a Bridged Adapter. And I am running a Java Application to try and connect to the VM.

Comment: Should I use a different type for my connection to the VM? @MosheKatz

Comment: What is running on the VM to accept the connection?

Comment: Bridged Adapter should work, assuming that your router isn't blocking the traffic.

Comment: "Currently I am trying to connect to the VM"  Connect to it how exactly? If they're answering pings, then you are communicating.

Comment: A server @MosheKatz

Comment: I can ping on the command terminal to the VM from the host machine but when I try to wireshark the traffice I don't see any traffic for that communication... @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007

Comment: My first thought is that the server application on the VM is listening to the wrong IP - most likely `localhost` on either `127.0.0.1`, `::1`. Are you running WireShark on the host or the VM?

Comment: I am running WireShark on the host @MosheKatz